# jquery autocomplete remote data source

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am new to jQuery. I am trying jQuery autocomplete remote data source here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Quanta Plus">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var cache = {},
            lastXhr;
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
          minLength: 2,
          source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;

            if ( term in cache ) {
              response( cache[ term ] );
              return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
              cache[ term ] = data;

              if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                response( data );
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div class="demo">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
        <input id="birds"  value="" />
      </div>
    </div><!-- End demo -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**FILE: search.php**

```
<?php 

require_once("includes/connection.php");

$q = strtolower($_GET["birds"]);
echo $q;
$return = array();

$query = "SELECT title
  FROM `project`
  WHERE `title` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '%$q%'
  USING latin1 )";

$resultset=mysql_query($query,$connection);

$json = '[';
$first = true;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
  if (!$first) {
    $json .=  ',';
  } else {
    $first = false;
  }

  $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['title'].'"}';
}

$json .= ']';

echo $json;

?>
```

**getting the following error:**

```
Notice:
Undefined
  index: birds in /var/www/html/workbench/sudeepc/project/search.php
  on line 4
    [
      {"value":"chandrayaan"},
      {"value":"Project Management System"},
      {"value":"shoping cart"},
      {"value":"hospital management system"}
    ]
```

fire bug show the following error while searching on that text box and there is no suggestion for search.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Apparently `$_GET["birds"]` doesn't exist. What happens if you replace that with `$_POST["birds"]`?

Comment: $q = strtolower($_POST["birds"]);  it result in the same error

Comment: Since he's calling `$.getJSON()`, it should be loading the data into `$_GET['birds']`. PHP wouldn't be throwing an error based on not having a GET value anyway - it would just have an empty value.

Comment: when i am typing in to text box a get request go to search.php GET http://......../search.php?term=sho
so i changed my search.php to  $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);  now there is no error fire bug shows sho[{"value":"shoping cart"}] in response 
but there is no auto complete appeared for the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, it appears that the first error was caused by looking for the wrong $_GET variable. Props to you for spotting that with Firebug and correcting it appropriately.

The reason that it is not filling in a value currently is because of the extra string echoed in front of the JSON. Remove the line `echo $q;` and it should work.